# Read properties file from jar using jstl setBundle on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, properties, jstl

All my web app are using a comum JAR file. I'd like to get my framework version, that is into a .properties file, and show it on footer page.

I want to read this properties using jstl setBundle tag.

This is the version.properties file:

```
deploy_version=1.02
data_deploy=2013/06/04 14\:08
computador_deploy=EG1188930
usuario_deploy=1542069
```

I'm trying this on my jsp, but I'm getting any value:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="br.gov.company.framework.version" var="framework"/>
<fmt:message key="deploy_version" bundle="${framework}"/>
```

The JAR file is located into \WEB-INF\lib.

Is there another way to get this from JSP? Or do I have to get it from Java getResourceAsStream?

Tnks!

Comment: The above line only sets a bundle. You need to get the property from inside the bundle, using an fmt:message tag. Did you do that? Could you show us your properties file and tell us which package it's located in.

Comment: Hi, I've used fmt:message. The .properties file is located into the root of the JAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties file is at the root of the jar file. So its basename is not `br.gov.company.framework.version`, but simply `version`:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="version" var="framework"/>
<fmt:message key="deploy_version" bundle="${framework}"/>
```

You would use `br.gov.company.framework.version` as the base name if the path of the file in the jar was `/br/gov/company/framework/version.properties`